# Django best Practice for checking user type using Model

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django project where I have Landlord, Agent and Prospect users and I want to check user type whenever a user logs in to determine the user type and redirect user appropriately, but my code does not work properly. Even when a valid user tries to login, the view redirects back to the login page. Some should help a brother.

Models:

```
class Landlord(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username



class Agent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Prospect(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='prospect_profile')
    payment_ref = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    payment_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    properties = models.ManyToManyField('Property', through='Tenancy')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def become_tenant(self, property):
        if self.payment_status:
            tenant = Tenancy.objects.create(tenant=self, property=property, agent=property.agent, landlord=property.landlord)
            return tenant
        else:
            return None

class Tenancy(models.Model):
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Prospect, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    property = models.ForeignKey('Property', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agent = models.ForeignKey('Agent', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    landlord = models.ForeignKey('Landlord', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.tenant} - {self.property}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tenancies'
```

View code:

```
def index(request):
    user = request.user

    if user:
        # Check if User Profile is completed with new image uploaded 
        def profile_complete(profile):
                    return (
                profile.full_name is not None and profile.full_name != '' and
                profile.phone_number is not None and profile.phone_number != '' and
                profile.email is not None and profile.email != '' and
                profile.address is not None and profile.address != '' and
                profile.image is not None and profile.image != 'avatar.jpg'
            )
        #Check if user is either a Landlord, Agent, or Prospect and Profile is completed and they have unread messages
        if Landlord.user == user or Agent.user == user:
            try:
                profile = Profile.objects.select_related('user').get(user=user)
                if not profile_complete(profile):
                    return redirect('account-profile-update')
                elif user.landlord == 'landlord':
                    # Get all logged in landlord Properties
                    landlord_properties = Property.objects.filter(landlord__user=user)
                    if not landlord_properties.exists():
                        return redirect('add-property')
                    # Check if landlord has any notifications with status False
                    elif Message.objects.filter(property__landlord=user.landlord, status=False).exists():
                        return redirect('inbox')
                    else:
                        return redirect('property-listing')
                elif Agent.user == user:
                    # Get all the logged in Agent Properties
                    agent_properties = Property.objects.filter(agent__user=user)
                    if not agent_properties.exists():
                        return redirect('add-property')
                    # Check ifagent has any notifications with status False
                    elif Message.objects.filter(property__agent=user.agent, status=False).exists():
                        return redirect('inbox') 
                    else:
                        return redirect('property-listing')
            except (Landlord.DoesNotExist, Agent.DoesNotExist): 
                pass
        #Check if user is Prospect and Profile is completed
        elif Prospect.user == user:
            try:
                #Match the logged in user with users in the Profile DB
                prospect_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
                #Check if Prospect Profile is completed and redirect
                if not profile_complete(prospect_profile):
                    return redirect('account-profile-update')
                elif Message.objects.filter(recipient=user, status=False).exists():
                    return redirect('inbox')
                else:
                    return redirect('listings')
            except Prospect.DoesNotExist:
                pass

    request.session['user_type'] = 'default'
    return redirect('account-login')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use hasattr function to check if logged in user is related to either a landlord, agent or prospect objects. And I realized that I was doing user type comparison with string.

```
def index(request):
user = request.user

if user:
    # Check if User Profile is completed with new image uploaded 
    def profile_complete(profile):
        return (
            profile.full_name is not None and profile.full_name != '' and
            profile.phone_number is not None and profile.phone_number != '' and
            profile.email is not None and profile.email != '' and
            profile.address is not None and profile.address != '' and
            profile.image is not None and profile.image != 'avatar.jpg'
        )
    #Check if user is either a Landlord, Agent, or Prospect and Profile is completed and they have unread messages
    if hasattr(user, 'landlord') or hasattr(user, 'agent'):
        try:
            profile = Profile.objects.select_related('user').get(user=user)
            if not profile_complete(profile):
                return redirect('account-profile-update')
            elif hasattr(user, 'landlord'):
                # Get all logged in landlord Properties
                landlord_properties = Property.objects.filter(landlord__user=user)
                if not landlord_properties.exists():
                    return redirect('add-property')
                # Check if landlord has any notifications with status False
                elif Message.objects.filter(property__landlord=user.landlord, status=False).exists():
                    return redirect('inbox')
                else:
                    return redirect('property-listing')
            elif Agent.user == user:
                # Get all the logged in Agent Properties
                agent_properties = Property.objects.filter(agent__user=user)
                if not agent_properties.exists():
                    return redirect('add-property')
                # Check ifagent has any notifications with status False
                elif Message.objects.filter(property__agent=user.agent, status=False).exists():
                    return redirect('inbox') 
                else:
                    return redirect('property-listing')
        except (Landlord.DoesNotExist, Agent.DoesNotExist): 
            pass
    #Check if user is Prospect and Profile is completed
    elif hasattr(user, 'prospect_profile'):
        try:
            #Match the logged in user with users in the Profile DB
            prospect_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
            #Check if Prospect Profile is completed and redirect
            if not profile_complete(prospect_profile):
                return redirect('account-profile-update')
            elif Message.objects.filter(recipient=user, status=False).exists():
                return redirect('inbox')
            else:
                return redirect('listings')
        except Prospect.DoesNotExist:
            pass

 


request.session['user_type'] = 'default'
return redirect('account-login')
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this isn't a direct answer to your problem, however, it is a way to organise your code better and by doing so perhaps allow you to better understand the code and find the answer yourself and learn.

First, use Django shell to understand the types of objects you are dealing with.

`python manage.py shell` (it will be better if you have something like `ipython` installed in your python environment.

If you then do:

```
import Landlord

Landlord.user
```

You will see that this is something similar to `<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors...` so, you are not comparing the type of the user.

Secondly; if you look at your models. You can see that most of your user related models share the same code. Here's where you can use Abstract Models https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Something like:

```
AGENT = "agent"
LANDLORD = "landlord"
PROSPECT = "prospect"
TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (AGENT, "Agent"),
    (LANDLORD, "Landlord"),
    (PROSPECT, "Prospect"),
)

class BaseUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=AGENT)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Landlord(BaseUser):
    # custom code for landlord
    pass


class Agent(BaseUser):
    # custom code for agent
    pass

class Prospect(BaseUser):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='prospect_profile')
    payment_ref = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    payment_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    properties = models.ManyToManyField('Property', through='Tenancy')

    def become_tenant(self, property):
        # code ...
        pass
```

Then you can simply check this `user_type` property against what you need.

```
from my.models import AGENT, LANDLORD, PROSPECT

# code ...

if request.user.user_type == AGENT:
    # logged in user is an agent
    pass
```

Additionally, think about moving the code to check if there are any unread messages to the `BaseUser` class as a method inside it. Then you can simply do `user.has_unread_messages()` on the views and keep it clean and leave the logic and DB checks within the models file.